# Обращение к функции из fragment

Tags: java, android

Ребят, помогите решить проблему. Чтобы воспользоваться функцией, ее надо сделать статичной. Делая, функцию статичной, создается ошибка:

```
non-static method getActivity() cannot be referenced from a static context
non-static variable FILENAME cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Хотя, всего лишь пытаюсь сделать:

```
FILENAME = "file1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно делать статичной - получите экземпляр, приведите к Вашему типу и используйте:

```
 YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
 activity.someMethod();
```

Comment: Если, не трудно можно поподробней, пожалуйста

Comment: Лекцию провести или всё-таки скажете что именно Вам непонятно? Дополните вопрос так, что бы мы понимали чего Вы хотите.

Comment: Как я понял, вместо youractivity, надо подставить, то активити из которого мы хотим вызвать функцию. Как правильно оформить?